# Vision System: neural activity is modulated using FSK?

Tags: vision, human-eye, neuron, artificial-neural-network

I’m learning about the human vision system and signaling. **Does anyone know if the signaling used by the vision system is modulated at the neuron using amplitude frequency shift keying?**

I present my understanding of this below.

It’s my understanding that the rods and cones of the retina have a mechanism involving opsin and a geometry change which ultimately causes neurotransmitters to signal. This signal is an action potential over an axon ion channel.  The neurotransmitters in the vision signal path excite, inhibit or neither. This [results in three frequencies](https://www.jneurosci.org/content/27/36/9623) of signal over the ion channel corresponding to the retina receiving light (20 Hz), no light (1.7 Hz) or unknown/baseline (.19 Hz). The [light intensity changes the amplitude](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/9/18/3673/htm) or voltage of the signal.

Comment: I think this is a case where you're much better off learning about how neurons work first, and then much later trying to relate this to other things you already know about, say, technological radio communication. It'll be way less confusing that way. There are definitely not only 3 possible firing frequencies, though; neurons can fire at any frequency from never up to a maximum governed by the kinetics of their ion channels (100 Hz would be a reasonable expected maximum for a typical neuron).

Comment: A good place to start might be understanding the individual figures in your links.